# Throwing errors using async/await in AWS Lambda node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await, throw

I am trying to throw an error to the calling function and the error is not getting captured. The exception is not propagating to the calling function.

```
'use strict';

const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool();

var result;

exports.handler = async (event) => {
   
  var payload = event;
  try{
     result = await insertOrder(payload, 'test');
   }
   catch (err) {
     console.error("Error from main: " + err);
     throw err ;
  }
 return result;
};


async function insertOrder(payload, name)
{ 
 const client = await pool.connect();
 try{
    const queryString = {
        text: "INSERT INTO public.orders(payload, shop_name)" +
              "VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id",
        values: [payload, name],
    };

    const result = await client.query(queryString);       
    var orderId = result.rows[0].id;
    
  }
  catch (err) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK');
    console.log("Error from child: " + err);
    throw err;
  }
  finally {
    client.release();
    return orderId;
  }
}
```

Here is what is written to the log:

INFO    Error from child: error: INSERT has more target columns than expressions

The console.error in the calling function is not written to the log. What am I am missing? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Moving return orderId; to try block solved my issue